# Fluid snake animation using images

Tags: android, algorithm, andengine

I want create a snake game in Android using AndEngine. But in my game, the snake won't be controlled by the player. It'll just move in random directions.

I have a snake that can move in random directions. My problem is that I want **real-time animation** (i.e. the snake shouldn't just move after a delay).

I tried using register modifiers to move the snake, and that works. But the problem is that **I have images for each snake's tail element**.

If I had just rectangles, I would know how do this, but I'm using more advenced images.

When the snake changes direction, I should have an element connecting different directions (example: right and down).

[image]

**Is there any algorithm for this? Alternatively, where I can find an open source project that explains this?**

Answer (score 0):

It's the same with rectangles. Ideally you wouldn't delete the images for the time of the animation.